# How are images read in CNNs?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

When using `CNNs (Convolution Neural Networks)`, what is the most efficient way to feed images `(RGB format or any other format)` to the network ?

Can we feed the images same as they are i.e, pixel values ranging from `[0, 255]` or do we have to normalize them by dividing by `255` ?

Or what are the other ways of feeding the images to the network ?

Comment: many discussions are related to your question. I think the best is to do your experiments and find what is the best for your architecture and what helps your network to converge better and faster.

Comment: Can you post the links to such discussions ?

Comment: have look here in Data Preprocessing before you google it. http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/41184687/562769